# Python loop does not always break

Tags: python, random, sample

I have written a loop that samples from an existing pool of images to create a (pseudo-)randomized list. The goal is to have a list where the images appear a specific number of times but without consecutively repeating the same image.

I have tried the following code:

```
import random

number_img1 = number_img2 = 2
number_img3 = number_img4 = 4
number_img5 = number_img6 = 6

total_images = number_img1 + number_img2 + \
    number_img3 + number_img4 + number_img5 + number_img6

stimulus_full_random = []
new_item = 0

while len(stimulus_full_random) < total_images:
    new_item = random.choice(stimulus_full)
    if len(stimulus_full_random) == 0:
        stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
    elif 0 < len(stimulus_full_random) < total_images:
        if new_item == "img1_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img1_full") < number_img1:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
        elif new_item == "img2_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img2_full") < number_img2:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
        elif new_item == "img3_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img3_full") < number_img3:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
        elif new_item == "img4_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img4_full") < number_img4:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
        elif new_item == "img5_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img5_full") < number_img5:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
        elif new_item == "img6_full" and stimulus_full_random.count("img6_full") < number_img6:
            if new_item != stimulus_full_random[-1]:
                stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
            else:
                stimulus_full_random[-1] = new_item
    else:
        break

print(stimulus_full_random)
```

In some cases, it produces the desired output but sometimes, the loop does not break / the program runs on forever. I have tried several different versions, but always the same result. I am fairly new to programming and I do not understand why (only in some instances) this code does not work. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: else:
        break should be outside of if/else condition block.

Comment: It's hard to read. You should do some factorisation because most of your code does the same job with a different image number. Think about it: would you write 20 if-else if you had to support 20 images? What about 100 or 1M images?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to remove the elements that you cannot pick for next choice. For example, if you have 3 choices 'A', 'B' and 'C' and your last pick was 'A', since you cannot repeat it you can simply use `random(['B', 'C'])`.

Note that sometimes it is not possible to finish the sequence, if random happens badly. For example, with 'AAABBC', if you randomly choose the 5 first like 'ABCBA', you cannot pick the 6th without repeating 'A'. Maybe this code can interest you.

```
import random

stimulus_full = {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
total_images = sum(list(stimulus_full.values()))
stimulus_remaining = list(stimulus_full.keys())
stimulus_full_random = []
new_item = ''

while len(stimulus_full_random) < total_images:
    stimulus_possible = [
        elem for elem in stimulus_remaining if elem != new_item]
    if len(stimulus_possible) == 0:
        print('sequence not possible')
        break
    new_item = random.choice(stimulus_possible)
    stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
    if (stimulus_full_random.count(new_item) == stimulus_full[new_item]):
        stimulus_remaining.remove(new_item)

print('RESULT', stimulus_full_random)
```

Other advice, instead of :

```
number_img1 = number_img2 = 2
number_img3 = number_img4 = 4
number_img5 = number_img6 = 6
```

you can implement `number_imgs = [2,2,4,4,6,6]`

And a general advice since you are "fairly new to programming" : when your code does not work, try to implement a simpler case, with "ABC" instead of img1_full, img2_full,...img6_full for example. It is easier to debug.

**EDIT**

To restart the loop when the sequence is not possible, consider this code :

```
import random

stimulus_full = {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
total_images = sum(list(stimulus_full.values()))
stimulus_remaining = list(stimulus_full.keys())
stimulus_full_random = []
new_item = ''
sequence_failed = False

while len(stimulus_full_random) < total_images or sequence_failed:
    sequence_failed = False
    stimulus_possible = [
        elem for elem in stimulus_remaining if elem != new_item]
    if len(stimulus_possible) == 0:
        print('sequence not possible, retrying...')
        sequence_failed = True
        stimulus_full_random = []
        stimulus_remaining = list(stimulus_full.keys())
    else:
        new_item = random.choice(stimulus_possible)
        stimulus_full_random.append(new_item)
        if (stimulus_full_random.count(new_item) == stimulus_full[new_item]):
            stimulus_remaining.remove(new_item)

print('RESULT', stimulus_full_random)
```

Comment: Thank your for your advice. This solution works great! I'll make sure to try a simpler case next time.

Comment: I wondered if there is any way to restart the loop from the beginning if the sequence is not possible so that a complete list can be generated every time the code is run?

Comment: Of course it is possible, have a check at my EDIT part ;)

Comment: That is really neat! Thank you, I've learned a lot from this :)